# Unexpected error in simple recursion(Scheme Language)

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I'm learning Scheme using racket. I made the following program but it gives a contract violation error.

expected: (exact-nonnegative-integer? . -> . any/c)
given: '()

The program finds a list of all numbers in an interval which are divisible by 3 or 5.

```
#lang racket

;;Global Definitions
(define upper-bound 10)
(define lower-bound 0)


;;set-bounds: Int, Int -> ()
(define (set-bounds m n)
(set! upper-bound (max m n))
(set! lower-bound (min m n)))

;;get-numbers: () -> (Int)
(define (get-numbers)
    (build-list upper-bound '()))

;;make-list: Int, (Int) -> (Int)
(define (build-list x y)
    (cond
        [(= x lower-bound) y]
        [(= (modulo x 5) 0) (build-list (sub1 x) (cons x y))]
        [(= (modulo x 3) 0) (build-list (sub1 x) (cons x y))]
        [else (build-list (sub1 x) y)]))
```

EDIT: I made the changes suggested by Oscar Lopez.

Comment: A minor quip: an empty list should be defined as `'()`, not as `\`()` (that is: use a single quote, not a back tick, which means something different.)

Comment: no, the program as shown does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @WillNess I know. I run it using the REPL. Sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Earlier I used empty. It still didn't work. What's the difference between these two? I mean in the REPL it just works like '() should.

Comment: Empty and '() are the same

Comment: you ran *what* in the REPL? you haven't shown the call. nor the contract definition, without it the function just loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative method can be with the use of `for/list` to create the list:

```
(define (build-list ub lst)
  (for/list ((i (range lb ub))
             #:when (or (= 0 (modulo i 3))
                        (= 0 (modulo i 5))))
    i))
```

Usage:

```
(define lb 0)
(build-list 10 '())
```

Output:

```
'(0 3 5 6 9)
```

Edit:

Actually lst is not needed here:

```
(define (build-list ub)
  (for/list ((i (range lb ub))
             #:when (or (= 0 (modulo i 3))
                        (= 0 (modulo i 5))))
    i))
```

So one can call:

```
(build-list 10)
```

Following is a modification of the recursion method (uses 'named let'):

```
(define (build-list2 ub)
  (let loop ((x ub) (lst '()))
    (cond
        [(= x lb) lst]
        [(= (modulo x 5) 0) (loop (sub1 x) (cons x lst))]
        [(= (modulo x 3) 0) (loop (sub1 x) (cons x lst))]
        [else (loop (sub1 x) lst)])))
```

Also, if you always have to call your function with an empty list '(), you can put this as default in your argument list:

```
(build-list x (y '()))
```

Then you can call with simplified command:

```
(build-list 10)
```

Comment: I just wanted to try that approach and see how to do things that way. But anyway, thanks I'll also try this version.

Comment: Thanks for the recursive solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should test *first* the condition where the recursion stops - namely, when `x` equals the `lower-bound`:

```
(define (build-list x y)
  (cond
    [(= x lower-bound) y]
    [(= (modulo x 5) 0) (build-list (sub1 x) (cons x y))]
    [(= (modulo x 3) 0) (build-list (sub1 x) (cons x y))]
    [else (build-list (sub1 x) y)]))
```

Comment: I moved the lower-bound condition to the top just as you said. But still it gives me the same error. I understand the reason for placing it at top though.

Comment: I think the problem is in the types declared for `build-list`, are you using typed racket? it should be `make-list: Int, Int -> (Int)`

Comment: I am just using 'out of the box' racket installation. So, I guess its not typed racket. I just added the types because I read at some website that it is a good practice.

Comment: Then try deleting them :P because out of the box, the above code works for me